# Copying array into another array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

edit: It turns out that there was code in the main method that was contradicting the results of this snippet of code. It was just a case of me not paying close enough attention to my methods. Sorry for wasting your time.

I'm trying to copy and existing array called list into a new array called array. I am successful in copying the list into a new array but when I try to test the code, the last number that is printed out is the length of the array minus 1. I'm struggling to figure out why this keeps happening and was hoping for some help.

```
int[] array = new int[size];

    for(int x = 0;x < array.length;x++){
        array[x] = list[x];
        System.out.println(array[x]);
    }
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using `int[] array = Arrays.copyOf(list, list.length)`?

Comment: Please show the simplest set of code (including test data) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm trying to copy a partially filled array

Comment: @s24569 OK, so `Arrays.copyOf(list, size)`.

Comment: I'm assuming this is Java, so how are you able to access an item using the angle brackets, i.e. something reserved for arrays, and not the `get` method for lists? You should include the rest of your code.

Comment: Array elements are numbered from zero to length-1.  Why do you expect it to go from zero to length? That would be one too many.

Comment: I can just assume that your `size` variable is set to `.length - 1`

Comment: @Tom why whould he get an exception?

Comment: @SchokokuchenBäcker Arr, right, he uses `array.length`, not `list.length` in the `for` loop. Don't know how I mixed that up -.-

Answer (score 0):

I use the Arrays.copyOf() to copy the elements:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        int[] array = Arrays.copyOf(list, list.length);
        for(int x = 0;x < array.length;x++){
            array[x] = list[x];
            System.out.println(array[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

And the results are:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
int[] A = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
int[] B = A.clone();
```

or

```
int[] B = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, 0, A.length);
```

Also.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I code for your problem.Check your code with my or run my code for solving problem.
I hope this is helpful for you.